# Could RoR cucumber and capybara to test db record directly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I understand `cucumber` and `capybara` are to mimic user actions to test web application. However, is it possible or recommended if I directly to fetch db record to have a test if some attributes are unable to find from web interface directly?

If yes, how to locate the db record created by current test case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not recommended, but is possible, to do direct database access tests in feature tests. The main reason for this is that feature tests are intended to be black box tests that test a specific feature in the application from a users experience perspective (and users can't see into the DB, well shouldn't be able to anyway). In that case even though the value of some attribute of an object isn't technically visible in the UI the attribute has to have some effect on the record when shown (otherwise why have the attribute in the first place), and that effect should be testable via the UI.

In the rare cases where you do actually need to do direct database access you need to remember that you need to control synchronization between the UI and when you test the DB.  For example the following test code would lead to at best flaky tests.

```
...
click_button('Do something')
expect(MyObject.last.some_attribute).to be true
...
```

This is because once the button has been clicked Capybara doesn't know about any further actions that click creates, and just returns.  Then the DB access occurs before the request generated by the button click is processed and either there is no record yet, you're testing against the wrong record, or the state of the record hasn't been updated yet and the test fails. To fix this you need to insert an expectation between the click and the DB check to wait for the triggered action to finish

```
...
click_button('Do something')
expect(page).to have_content('Something has been done') # UI check that will succeed when the triggered action has completed
expect(MyObject.last.some_attribute).to be true
...
```

As for how to identify the DB record you want, you control all the test data, and it should be reset for every test.  That way if you've just created a record it should be the last record (`MyObject.last`).  If you're editing a record then you created the initial record in the setup for the test and should have access to it (`my_test_object.reload...`), etc...